# Como reemplazar datos usando np.where()

Tags: pandas, numpy

Soy nuevo programando y quiero realizar lo siguiente:

Tengo múltiples columnas, pero en particular tengo una con CIUDADES (texto), pero hay una en particular que se repite mucho "SANTIAGO", por lo cual quiero transformar esa ciudad en "SI" y todo el resto de ciudades en "NO".  Use un código, pero solo me devuelve una información, pero no reemplazo los datos.

Gracias

[image: Aqui el codigo usado]

Comment: Creo que lo que te falta es re-asignar lo que np.where retorna:  data_set['CIUDAD'] = np.where((data_set['CIUDAD'] =='SANTIAGO'), 'si','no')

Answer (score 0):

Tambien tuve que crear una nueva variable (columna) para que pudiera funcionar. Abajo el comando como quedó.

```
data_set['N_CIUDAD'] = np.where((data_set['CIUDAD']=='SANTIAGO'), 'Si', 'No')
```